# How can I move my partition in GParted?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

The following is a screenshot of GParted running on my system. There is a small unallocated space at the beginning of the list. This 1 MiB space is kind of annoying and I'd like to merge with any other partition except /dev/sda1, /dev/sda6 and /dev/sda4. When I right click on the unallocated partition, the only available operation is "New". And, if I click on "New", I get the following error message.

> It is not possible to create more than 4 primary partitions

Any ideas how to go about merging the small unallocated space with other partitions?

[image: GParted Screenshot]

Comment: Is 1Mb really worth the hassle, and the risk that something might go drastically wrong (power cut for example) during the move/resize operations?

Comment: For the larger unallocated space, will it allow the resizing of the extended partition (sda3) to butt up to sda2?

Comment: No, it doesn't let me resize sda3 to fill out the large unallocated space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like GParted is pretty limited. It doesn't even let me combine the unallocated space with the adjacent extended partition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only add that space to an adjacent partition (since all of the partitions on the disk are contiguous), otherwise you're talking about moving data within the partition and gparted can't handle that without a native windows FS tool to move the data.  I could be wrong, however.

But really, it isn't worth it.

Comment: If someone is going to mark me down, please comment if you know so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the 1MB gap is Windows7 trying to cater for the different ways operating systems treat disk geometry. This is very unlikely to be a concern for most people, I would think.

I would also add that you can delete that system-reserved partition if you don't use Bitlocker, Windowsboot manager, and the windows recovery environment. (The partition is optional, you can even [prevent it from being created](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/08/20/hack-to-remove-100-mb-system-reserved-partition-when-installing-windows-7/) during windows set up)

Comment: I'd prefer to keep that system-reserved partition as it is.